# What is the Oracle equivalent of the Informix `interval` function?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, informix

I have been tasked with converting some scripts referencing an Informix database to be compatible with a new Oracle database.

I thought I would start out by going through the individual scripts and looking for function calls that may vary syntactically between Informix and Oracle. I had been able to find the Oracle equivalent for most of the function calls I came across, however this one has me a little stumped:

```
where f.writetime > current - interval(xxx) day to day
```

What exactly does that function mean, particularly the `(xxx)` part and what is the Oracle equivalent?

Comment: You may also come across `DATETIME(YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.fffff) YEAR TO FRACTION(5)`.  This is equivalent to a `TIMESTAMP` in Standard SQL.  Informix has some variations which can't be represented directly in SQL Standard types; the canonical example is `DATETIME(mm-dd HH:MM) MONTH TO MINUTE`.  Fortunately such usages are rare.  `DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE` is less rare, but you can graft on the seconds (as zero) easily enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a function call - it's Informix SQL's `INTERVAL` [data type literal syntax](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/sqlr127.htm).

Oracle SQL supports the [interval data type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i38598) as well.

I would expect that oracle would give a similar result with

```
WHERE f.writetime > current_timestamp - INTERVAL 'xxx' DAY TO DAY
```

Essentially, when the writetime is greater than the current time minus xxx days.

Comment: @N West That makes sense. I had basically put the same thing together, but wasn't really sure what to do/make of the `xxx` part. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oracle probably doesn't _need_ the `DAY TO DAY` when the from and to units are the same; you could write `INTERVAL 'xxx' DAY` in standard SQL.  It probably doesn't reject `DAY TO DAY`, either.  (Informix requires both the start and the end unit, always.)